# how do I target the first child of the first appearance of an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok so I have several blocks of code that look like:

```
    <div class="news-sec">
        <h3 class="col-xs-8">heading</h3>
        <p class="col-xs-4>paragraph</p>
    </div>
  <div class="news-sec">
        <h3 class="col-xs-8">heading</h3>
        <p class="col-xs-4>paragraph</p>
    </div>
  <div class="news-sec">
        <h3 class="col-xs-8">heading</h3>
        <p class="col-xs-4>paragraph</p>
    </div>
```

My trouble is that the class is being output by drupal. I need the first one not to have the bootstrap classes, however because they are all the same field they all get spit out wrapped up in the `col-xs-#` divs. I figure I can write some css to negate the effects of bootstrap such as:

```
.news-sec h3:first-of-type{
    width:100%;
    float:none;
}
```

What I've learned though is that this will affect every `.news-sec` top level `h3` instead of looking at only the first `.news-sec`.
Is there a way to accomplish what I want to do without js.

PS My drupal dev is out for the week and I can't edit the way it's being output, only after.

Comment: What about [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)?

Comment: you need [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) and if negation is also required, look for `:not`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.news-sec:first-child h3` is what you want. This gets the first `.news-sec` and applies the style to its `h3`. Note how I've applied the pseudo selector (`:first-child`) to the `.news-sec` instead of the `h3`

*(Compare this to your code: `.news-sec h3:first-of-type` -- Your code was looking for the first `h3` inside of all `.news-sec`)*

Here's a demo:

```css
.news-sec:first-child h3 {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="news-sec">
  <h3 class="col-xs-8">heading</h3>
  <p class="col-xs-4">paragraph</p>
</div>
<div class=" news-sec ">
  <h3 class="col-xs-8">heading</h3>
  <p class="col-xs-4">paragraph</p>
</div>
<div class="news-sec">
  <h3 class="col-xs-8">heading</h3>
  <p class="col-xs-4">paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Side note: You're missing some quotes in your provided HTML code near each `col-xs-4`.

Comment: shouldn't those `div.news-sec` be wrapped with some other tag, just to be sure? `first-child` selector works when the element is the first of a group of siblings, AFAIK.

Comment: Correct. I'm going off what code the OP provided. Since three `col-xs-4` divs exist, I'm assuming that it is an entire 12-column row. If so, this would be wrapped in a `div` anyway, since it's bootstrap. So it should work fine.

Comment: @Sebastianb This code work as is, based on the given code, and if the OP _forgot_ something, we can't anticipate that and give an answer covering what we don't know

Comment: @LGSon true, I just thought to add some kind of clarification, given the usual confusion with [first-child](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8539107/5796253)

Comment: @Sebastianb What better would be to explain the difference between `first-of-type`, which OP had in the question (for some reason), with the now suggested `first-child`

Comment: Read the first part. You can read about it in MDN too, for that matter. My point is that there's usually some confusion with first-child, that's all. If for some reason his set of `.news-sec` weren't the first elements of the parent, this wouldn't work, thus the reason why I thought it would be nice to clarify it.

Comment: @Sebastianb If you assume I don't know the difference, that is not the case, I mean for users that does not know...and the answer does not give any such explanation

Comment: @LGSon An explanation of the difference is not relevant to answering the question. OP was applying the pseudo selector to the wrong element, which is a common confusion.

Comment: @WesFoster Why not?... After all, OP used it in the question, and, in this case, if you were to use `first-of-type` in the correct way, that would also target the first h3 in the same way `first-child` does

Comment: I think I've been misunderstood. I'm not talking about first-of-type, I'm talking about first-child. The first paragraph of the linked answer talked about the confusion in its use.

Answer (score 0):

`.news-sec h3:first-child` targets the first and only the first.

Comment: That targets the "first and only the first" `h3`. Certainly not the `.news-sec`, which is what the OP is trying to do. Your answer is essentially the same problem the OP is having.

Comment: That what he wanted to do, the selected answer uses the same thing.

Comment: The correct answer is applying the pseudo selector to the `.news-sec` and not to the `h3` like you, and the OP, have done. Look again.

Comment: Ahh, yes. Sorry about that.